# JavaScript code doesn't work

Tags: javascript, function

HTML CODE

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Price List </title>

</head>

<body>

<h1> PRICELIST </h1>
<form id="formSearch">
<div>
<label for="searchBox"> Search products here: </label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Type text here to search product" id="searchBox">
</div>
<div id="buttons">
<button id="getAll"> GET ALL PRODUCTS</button>
</div>

</form>

<div id="outputPlace">

</div>


<script src="product.js"></script>
</body>


</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
(function(){                    //start anonymous function

var list= {

  "listOfProducts": [

  {
  "name":"hard disk",
  "price": "50$",
  "quality":"good",
  },
  {
  "name":"monitor",
  "price":"100$",
  "quality": "very good",
  },
  {
  "name":"speakers",
  "price":"20$",
  "quality": "not bad",
  },
  {
  "name":"headphones",
  "price":"12$",
  "quality":"bad",
  },
  {
  "name": "mobile phone",
  "price": "300$",
  "quality": "excellent",
  },
  {
  "name": "usb memory",
  "price": "30$",
  "quality": "the best",
  }
  ]
},

 target=document.getElementById("outputPlace"),
    searchForm=document.getElementById("formSearch"),
    productList=list.listOfProducts,
    listLength=productList.length,
    searchValue=document.getElementById("searchBox"),
    searchInput=searchValue.value;




var listMethods = {

searchList: function(event) {

event.preventDefault();
var i;
target.innerHTML="";
if(listLength>0 && searchInput!=="") {

   for(i=0;i<listLength;i++) {
   var product=productList[i],
       whatIsFound=product.name.indexOf(searchInput);
       if(whatIsFound!==-1){

       target.innerHTML+='<p>'+product.name+', '+product.price+', '+product.quality+'<a href="http//www.facebook.com">click here to buy</a></p>'
       }

   }


}





}





};

searchForm.addEventListener("submit",listMethods.searchList,false);








}) (); //end anonymous function
```

I need someone to help me with my code. I don't know why it doesn't work. It is a simple search box. Do not pay attention to button. The code should be executed when I press Enter, as you can see in the code. I am a begginer and I am trying for few hours to find my mistake.

Comment: Needs a fiddle, and an explanation of what you expect it to do and what it is doing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Checkout the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) as your missing some critical information for us to help you with your problem.

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice in a row. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17844543/cant-find-error-in-my-code edit the original.

Comment: @rlemon: It's not the same code, he did apply [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17844580/1048572). Since that wasn't the only mistake, he was suggested to ask another question.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, now it is working! :) like rlemon said, i was suggested to ask another question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> searchInput=searchValue.value;
> ```

That will get the `.value` property of the `<input>` when it is executed, instead of creating a pointer to it. The variable `searchInput` will just contain the empty string, and that won't change.

Move that assignment into the event handler to retrieve the value when the button is clicked, and it will work.

([working demo at jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/2JHer/), also fixed the syntax error mentioned by @KevinBowersox)

Answer (score 0):

This object literal won't fly in `IE` you have extra commas at the end of the properties list.

```
var list= {

  "listOfProducts": [

  {
  "name":"hard disk",
  "price": "50$",
  "quality":"good", <-- remove these since there is no property after
  },
  {
  "name":"monitor",
  "price":"100$",
  "quality": "very good", <-- remove these since there is no property after
  },
  //rest of object omitted, still needs changed...
}; <-- end with semicolon
```

Also the anonymous function (I assume self executing?) is not properly closed.

```
(function(){
  //code goes in here

})(); <--- This piece is missing;
```

I would recommend getting a good Javascript editor such as Aptana.  These simple syntax errors would have been identified very quickly.

Comment: No, he should not end the object literal with a semicolon; it's a multi-variable declaration. And the "*This piece is missing*" is right in his code: `}) (); //end anonymous function` (not my downvote, the rest of the answer is very valid!)